# Chrome Remote Desktop on 15.10

Tags: 15.10, remote-access

I have the CRD (Chrome Remote Desktop) installed on my Ubuntu machine, and I am able to "share" from it, and "access" from another computer. But I want to add it as one of my "computers".

Whenever I try to enable it, I get asked to enter a new pin, and after a short time of "enabling" spinner running around, it seems to have worked. However, if I then try to connect to the new machine, from the same computer, or from a different one (on my same home computer, or through the internet), I quickly get the following message: "The remote computer is not responding to connection requests. Please verify that it is online and try again."

I am %100 sure the computer is online, just to make it clear.

I managed to get it to work a long time ago, by some voodoo. I'm not sure how. But later I upgraded my 15.04 to 15.10, and it hasn't worked since.

Is it even supposed to work? Is anybody here using CRD to access his Ubuntu computer?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I got it to work using the info at the thread in (https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/2fHNvGUHJ3B)
There are all kinds of changes, and it worked for me before posting the question here, and then stopped working. Doing it again from scratch finally got it working again.
My current chrome-remote-desktop file is here - http://pastebin.com/WWqNKfum